# How do you toggle the visibility of a div in FF with javascript? (IE and Chrome work fine)

Tags: javascript, firefox, html, layer

So, I'm trying to toggle the visibility of a div layer using javascript and this is what it looks like:

```
document.all["layer1"].style.visibility='visible';
```

and

```
document.all["layer1"].style.visibility='hidden';
```

What would the syntax look like for this if I'm trying to do it in Firefox? If I know that, then I'll add in an if statement to check if the browser is firefox and use the alternate code.

Comment: document.all generally works in Firefox if used as you describe it.  How are you actually using it, if it's not working for you?  Can you post a link to a full page showing the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`document.all` is a not a supported function, nor is it in the spec for the DOM ([Here](http://simonwillison.net/2003/Aug/11/documentAll/) is more on that). You will have to grab the div by another method.

[querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector)

```
document.querySelector('div#layer1').style.visibility = 'hidden';    
document.querySelector('div#layer1').style.visibility = 'visible';
```

OR

[getElemenyById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById)

```
document.getElementById('layer1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById('layer1').style.visibility = 'visible';
```

are two major methods.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `document.all[]`. It is not supported by all browsers, and is largely an artifact of the IE4 days.  Instead use `document.getElementById()` to access the `<div>`'s id attribute:

```
document.getElementById("layer1").style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById("layer1").style.visibility = 'visible';
```

Comment: Yeah, I learned javascript off of a book printed in the 90s so that makes sense. I'll try that

Comment: @AlexDatcu Oh by all means get some newer books! JavaScript has matured so much since then. I recommend Douglas Crockford's JavaScript: The Good Parts and David Flanagan's Javascript: The Definitive Guide

Comment: Thanks! I'll see if I can get one of those

Answer (score 0):

You can use querySelectorAll, but you'll then need to loop through the elements.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.layer').forEach((element) => {
  element.style.visibility='hidden';
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Haxen2000/xo8k0eqp/6/

Answer (score -1):

```
//class named layer1
document.querySelectorAll('.layer1').style.display='none';
document.querySelectorAll('.layer1').style.display='block';
```

```
//id named layer1
document.querySelector('#layer1').style.display='none';
document.querySelector('#layer1').style.display='block';
```